# "aws dynamodb list-tables" is not working on ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I've created a node.js application which connects to DynamoDB. Everything is working fine locally Now I'm trying to setup on AWS servers.

1. First I've created DynamoDB tables from AWS DynamoDB console. It is working fine.
2. I've created a new role from IAM management console > Roles to access DynamoDB. And attached that role to EC2 instance.
   But when I fire any aws dynamodb cli command, it gave me error to mention the region.
3. So I went to IAM management console > Users, and created an access key to my admin type user.
4. Now I'm login to EC2 CLI using `ec2-user` and `aws configure` with previously generated access key.

```sh
AWS Access Key ID [None]: ACCESS KEY
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: SECRET
Default region name [None]: us-east-1
Default output format [None]: json
```

5. But when I use following command `aws dynamodb list-tables`. It gives no output, no error.

Comment: can you elaborate the steps a little more.

Comment: Check your region.

Comment: Also please don't put your admin access keys on your instance. Attach an IAM role to your instance instead and give it the least permissions necessary.

Comment: Generating AWS key alone is not enough. Or use search engine and look for something like "step by step configure dynamodb ec2" 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/authentication-and-access-control.html

Comment: @cementblocks how to remove the access key now?

Comment: after a long time waiting, got connect timeout "Max retries exceeded"

Comment: can it be because of SG outbound rules? Currently, I've set it to none.

Comment: So the problem has been solved by settings SG outbound rules to HTTPS. Now just need to find correct settings for IP address

Comment: The access key/secret are stored in `~/.aws/credentials`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, The main issue was outbound rules for attached security group. Here are the necessary things to do

1. Set a security group outbound rule to HTTPS
   [image]
2. Setup Credentials

   1. Create Access Key from IAM management console > Users.
   2. SSH to EC2 instance.
   3. Configure the credentials to EC2 instance using `aws configure` command or directly modify `~/.aws/credentials` file.
3. Attach Role

   1. Create Role from IAM management console > Roles. Select the role which is necessary to perform operation on AWS service. Eg `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess`
   2. Open VPC console and select the EC2 instance.
   3. Attach the role from Actions menu
      [image]

It is good, though optional, to [create VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints-dynamodb.html). If you face `UnauthorizedOperation` error while creating endpoint, assign `AmazonEC2FullAccess` permission to the user from IAM console. Remove it later if you don't need it.

To use the AWS service from your application, find the relevant endpoint from [this list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are having problems connecting to DynamoDB because of the way you have configured your VPC.

There are some options but if you would prefer to keep your VPC isolated from the internet then you could enable VPC endpoints for DynamoDB. That way you can access DynamoDB from within your VPC without those connections going over the public internet.

There is a step-by-step guide for how to do that here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints-dynamodb.html

Essentially, it involves the following steps:

1. you have to get the VPC id for the VPC where your EC2 instance is located
2. create a VPC endpoint for DynamoDB, specifying the VPC id and the regional dynamodb service name:

```
aws ec2 create-vpc-endpoint --service-name com.amazonaws.<region>.dynamodb --vpc-id <yourvpcid>
```

Comment: OP created Security Group with no outbound connections allowed. Creating VPC Endpoint for DynamoDB would not have fixed the problem.